# CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope and Form.Show()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to fix all my project warning according to Microsoft code analysis (CA:XXXXX)

One of the warning is "CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope"

My Code is:

```
Private sub Foo()
   Dim O As New Form1()
   O.Show()
End Sub
```

Visual studio says that the object O is not disposable, in such situation I can't use the keyword USING because I will lost the object O after `End Using`:

```
Private sub Foo()
   Using O As New Form1()
      O.Show()  'The form will open then close !!!
   End Using
End Sub
```

The form then will open and close

How to get ride with CA2000 in such situation, I don't need to ignore, I want to solve and fix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't need to ignore, I want to solve and fix.

This is, effectively, a false warning, in this specific instance.  You don't want to "solve and fix" this message in this specific case, because you want the object to "live" beyond the end of the local scope.

If you call `Dispose` on the object in that scope, you will (always) close the form, in this case.

Comment: Many thanks, you need to tell Microsoft not me :) I think there is more standard solution especially I'm facing huge memory with my project, very big, lots of GUI.

Comment: @Sameh CA2000 is a common one that provides false results, as there's no way to know whether an IDisposable should necessarily be Disposed or not.  That's part of why it's easy to ignore, and why it's a code analysis warning and not a compiler warning...

Comment: From my experience, always use standard and never ignore warnings unless you have a reason.  Standard = 99% Standard + 1% Exceptions   and only experienced ppl should use the 1% with know reasons

Comment: There are a lot of warnings that there aren't work arounds for. For instance, every time i set up a Try Catch Finally and dispose of a reader in my Finally statement it throws a warning because my reader hasn't been declared (i believe thats the warning). This is due to the declaration and use of the reader being in the Try and its possible it will throw an error before reaching the reader, which may cause it not to hold a value.

Answer (score 0):

How about `ShowDialog`?

```
Private sub Foo()
   Using O As New Form1()
      O.ShowDialog()
   End Using
End Sub
```

It will dispose all resources of `Form1` after i has been closed.

Comment: in this case yes, but not always you can use showdialog, I'm asking a generic question, ShowDialog block your app.